# Tim Chow's proof that the moser-number is much smaller than grahams number

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, big-numbers

The link [here](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/cyc/b/gmproof.htm) shows a proof from Tim Chow that the moser-number is much smaller than 
 grahams number.

I do not understand the inequality

3^^...^^3 (3^^^^^3×2-1 arrows) << G 2

What does G 2 mean here ?

If the sequence

$$G_1 = 3\uparrow^4 3$$

$$G_{n+1} = 3 \uparrow ^{G_n} 3$$

for all $n \ge 1$

is meant, I understand that the left number is much smaller then $G_3$, but I do not 
 understand that it must be smaller than $G_2$.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: [Probably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham's_number#Definition)

Comment: I think it does refer the mentioned $G$-sequence, but it's possible that the $G_k$ were defined with $G_0$ (rather than $G_1$) equal to $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$, which would make the stated comparison correct. Also, there seems to be a typo in the first application Lemma 2 (the "-1" should be "-5"), but it doesn't affect the conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the definition of $G$ from a [linked page](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/cyc/b/big.htm#graham), which is the one you posted, it is certainly the case that

$$3\underbrace{\uparrow\dots\uparrow}_{3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3\quad}3\gg G_2$$

I would assume it to be a typo and that they meant $G_3$.

---

As a sidenote: one does actually have $M<G_2$ and this can be easily proven using the tighter bounds of $a[k+1]\le a\downarrow^ka\le a\uparrow^ka$, using the up-arrow and down-arrow notations.